# Using templates as select option name in Aurelia

Tags: html, select, aurelia

I have a select in Aurelia that looks like

```
                        <select
                            name="car"
                            value.bind="car">
                            <option repeat.for="car of cars" model.bind="car.id">
                                ${car.name}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

Now, I want to display the name of the car, based on a condition, like

```
                            <template if.bind="mYcondition">
                                ${car.name}
                            </template>
                            <template if.bind="!mYcondition">
                                ${car.name} - ${getCarSeries.get(car.id)}
                            </template>
```

If I put this together, looks like

```
                        <select
                            name="car"
                            value.bind="car">
                            <option repeat.for="car of cars" model.bind="car.id">
                                <template if.bind="mYcondition">
                                     ${car.name}
                                </template>
                                <template if.bind="!mYcondition">
                                    ${car.name} - ${getCarSeries.get(car.id)}
                                 </template>
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

In this case, my IDE complains because of `Element template is not allowed here`.

Any way around it?

Comment: Try using a `span` instead?

Comment: Tried it already. `Element span is not allowed here`

Comment: Only text is allowed inside `option` element. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `get` method to your viewmodel that returns the display name, like so:

```
public get getDisplayName(car) {
  if (mYcondition) {
    return car.name;
  } else {
    return car.name + " - " this.getCarSeries.get(car.id);
  }
}
```

And then call that in your view:

```
<select name="car" value.bind="selectedCar">
  <option repeat.for="car of cars" model.bind="car.id">
     ${getDisplayName(car)}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I considered this already, but was hoping there's another way. I will accept this as answer for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

${mYcondition? car.name: car.name + ' - ' + getCarSeries.get(car.id)}